# List of nodes types in a query plan in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan

Where can I find an exhaustive list of possible nodes types(e.g. Seq scan, groupAggregate, Nested loop ...) that a query plan could contain in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Most (but not all) of them are listed an explained in a series of blog posts by depesz: http://www.depesz.com/2013/04/27/explaining-the-unexplainable-part-2/, http://www.depesz.com/2013/05/09/explaining-the-unexplainable-part-3/, http://www.depesz.com/2013/05/19/explaining-the-unexplainable-part-4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for a comprehensive list of types, without any explanations, [this piece of source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/commands/explain.c#L814) might be of help to you.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: This link appears to be broken now. I don't see any list of types as the linked line of code.